# Change IP address of NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use google translate api. so I have this:

```
const translatorB = require('@vitalets/google-translate-api').translate;
const { text, raw } = await translatorB(string, { from, to });
```

the issue is very soon I get this error:

> TooManyRequestsError: Too Many Requests IP: 80.120.58.179, Time:
> 2023-06-11T09:31:17Z, Url:
> https://translate.google.com/translate_a/single?client=at&dt=t&dt=rm&dj=1

How can I change the IP address of the node server to skip this error?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to bypass the API quota restrictions. This is generally not a good practice. Look into a paid service like https://cloud.google.com/translate

Answer (score 1):

The IP Address of a node server is based upon where it is hosted. Therefore, you would need to proxy/VPN your connection to bypass that, which may be difficult with an external package like the one you're using. As Chris' comment mentioned, you should probably use the official API for stuff like that. Check out google's translation API reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v2/nodejs).

If you don't *need* to use google's APIs, I would recommend a more freely available (and less complicated!) option.
For example, you could use the [translate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/translate) package with the [LibreTranslate](https://github.com/LibreTranslate/LibreTranslate) API (who even allow you to self-host, if you happen to go past any of their API Limits too)!